# Why is my Netstat not returning the desired output and just getting hung up?

Tags: linux, remote, netstat

My remote Linux machine is able to ping an IP address on an internet, but the same  action is unable to get the netstat report for that IP.

```
ping a.b.c.d
64 bytes from a.b.c.d: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.509 ms
64 bytes from a.b.c.d: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.249 ms
64 bytes from a.b.c.d: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.273 ms
64 bytes from a.b.c.d: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.357 ms
```

but netstat is unable to get the output of,

```
netstat -an a.b.c.d | grep <some port>
```

it's just getting hang and not even returning my prompt, while I already have been sure about the connections it should list.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't think `netstat` does what you think it does.

Comment: I wonder what `netstat -an IP` this would mean. Option `-a` lists all listening and non-listening sockets and `-n` shows numerical addresses. I think you misunderstood `Mr. netstat`.

Comment: meaning is same as that you said, except the output is expected for that IP, not considering the localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`netstat` [doesn't accept](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) an IP address argument. The *only* non-option argument is a delay, and that's not in all versions.

The command will

> Print network connections, routing tables, interface statistics, masquerade connections, and multicast memberships

**for the local machine**. It doesn't have any access to data about other machines, only connections to and from the machine it's running on. It can take a while to do that, and loop forever with a delay.

If you're interested in information about connections from your machine to a particular other IP address you can use `grep` for it. Note that `netstat` is deprecated in any case, and [its replacement `ss`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ss) has better inbuilt support for that use case.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but ss doesnt seem to be installed :(

Comment: is there any other way? I want to get to know the netstat-like details but not for localhost, some other internet ip..

Comment: No. Log in to the machine and run your commands there.